# Countif based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

For reference here's the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CS-fYhqeKRmEiJC5XA6kRIwIjyBDlBcXj-K9FHjCZjA/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to create a filter that shows me all the data for May based on type and course category. I highlighted these in blue in the sheet.

I worked out how to count the type and category using this formula:

```
=arrayformula(SUM(
 (Resolutions!D:D="Complaints")*(Resolutions!J:J="Training and Assessment")))
```

but I would like to further count by month in the future.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

how about using `=COUNTIFS()` ?

example:

> ```
> =COUNTIFS(A1:A10, ">20", 
>           B1:B10, "<30")
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> =COUNTIFS(A7:A24, ">6", 
>           B7:B24, "<" & DATE(1969,7,20))
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> =COUNTIFS(B8:B27, ">" & B12, 
>           C8:C27, "<" & C13, 
>           D8:D27, "<>10")
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> =COUNTIFS(C1:C100, "Yes")
> ```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?visit_id=1-636622437866841776-1023894088